# Getting Eval value from parent Data control

Tags: asp.net

I have a `DetailsView` with a `TemplateField` that contains a `GridView`.

When using `Eval` inside the `GridView` cells, I only get access to the data source of the `GridView`.

How can I access the data of the parent, i.e. the `DetailsView`?

Thank You

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="det1" DataSourceID="source1">
 <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTempalte>
     <asp:GridView ID="grid1" DataSourceID="source2">
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTempalte>
          //this is where I need a column from source1 while Eval only gives me source2
          <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("column from source1") %>'/>
         </ItemTempalte>
       </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
  </ItemTempalte>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Can you add your sample code for better understanding?

Comment: @HardikLeuwa added sample code

Answer (score 0):

How about skipping `Eval()`.  Try something like this

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# CType(source1.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)("column from source1") %>' />
```

You might need to inspect the object for `Source1`, to see if its `DataItem` is a `DataRowView`, or some other type.   I can't see your code where you defined `source1`, so I can only offer my best guess.